# How Do I Output Multiselect Attribute Values In Magento 2.3.x?

Tags: magento, magento2

In a Magento 2.3.3 store I am trying to ouput the values of a multiselect custom attribute on a category page, but not having any luck.
I have set the attribute to be used in product listing and tried to output it on catalog/product/listing.phtml template page in my custom theme.
I am using the using the following code:
`<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>`
This is working for dropdown attributes but not multi select attributes.
Kind of stuck on this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get MultiSelect Attribute value

create block in "catalog_product_view.xml"

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="attribue.name" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute_name.phtml" after="-"  /> 
</referenceBlock>
```

create "phtml" file under "Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute_name.phtml"

> ```
> <?php $product = $block->getProduct(); ?> 
> <div>
>   <?php 
>     $data = explode(',',$product->getData('attribute_code'));
>     foreach($data as $value):            
>   ?>
>   <?php 
>     $attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code');
>     if ($attr->usesSource()): 
>   ?>
>         <?php 
>             $option_value = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($value);
>         ?>
>         <p><?php echo $option_value; ?></p>
>     <?php endif;?>
>  <?php endforeach;?>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: When I use the above code, I get an error in the page. Is this for Magento 1 or Magento 2? I am using Magento 2.

Comment: for magento2, also you can use below code

<?php 
dropdown_id = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getDropdown(), 'dropdown');
$dropdown_attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('dropdown');
if ($dropdown_attr->usesSource()) {
    $dropdown = $dropdown_attr->getSource()->getOptionText($dropdown_id);
}
?>

Comment: This did not work either.
The page was blank after adding in the code for magento2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a code that returns "Multiselect Attribute Values". The attribute belongs to product entity. As it isn't a good idea to get ProductResource model from ProductModel and taking into account that probably you need to get it inside some template, just create a ViewModel and use this example there.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product as ProductResource;
...
public function __construct(
    ...
    ProductResource           $productResource
)
{
    ...
    $this->productResource = $productResource;
}

public function prepareProductAttributeOptions($product, $attributeCode)
{
    $result = [];
    $data = $product->getData($attributeCode);
    $optionsIds = [];
    if ($data) {
        $optionsIds = explode(',', $data);
    }

    foreach ($optionsIds as $optionId) {
        $attr = $this->productResource->getAttribute($attributeCode);
        if ($attr->usesSource()) {
            $option_value = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
            $result[] = $option_value;
        }
    }

    return implode(',', $result);

}
```

Comment: As a general rule, when posting code, please explain what it does and how it solves the problem at hand, and maybe how it's different from the existing answers. [cf](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Caesar What explanation do you need? It is an example of a code that returns "Multiselect Attribute Values". The attribute belongs to product entity as it was asked in a question. In a previous answers ProductResource model takes from ProductModel that is a bad practice, not to mention that this logic in a template must be used via ViewModel. That is the difference with an existing answers.